# JOptionPane cancel button won't cancel out of the window?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

So, I'm making a simple guessing game, and the program won't exit out of the loop when the user presses the cancel button. Here's the loop

```
while(playAgain = true){
        int n = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, fields, "Number guessing game", JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION);

        if(n == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION){
            playAgain = false;
        }

        int randomNumber = randomNumber();

        String guess = input.getText();
        compare(randomNumber, Integer.parseInt(guess));

    }
```

Answer (score 11):

it should be

```
while(playAgain == true){
```

or

```
while(playAgain){
```

don't assign [`=`]  true to `playagain` use comparison [`==`] .
what you do is assign true to playagain and then check is it true.so it's always true

Comment: Thank you! Now I feel like a dumb ass for making such a simple mistake!

Comment: Most programmers would prefer the second option :-)